# Making a gawk comand that splits Fastas work in perl

Tags: regex, perl, awk, system

Hi I'm using this gawk command to split a Fasta file:

```
gawk '/^>c/ {OUT=substr($0,2) ".fa";print " ">OUT}; OUT{print >OUT}' your_input
```

It works perfectly from the terminal. I just want to use it in a perl script using `system` and use a string as an input file, but i don't know how to do it.

I've tried this:

```
my $string = "secuence.fa"; #this is the file I wanna split .

my $cmd= (gawk '/^>c/ {OUT=substr($0,2) ".fa";print " ">OUT}; OUT{print >OUT}' $string);
system $command;
```

When I run the script it says that I have some syntax error in `$cmd` but I cannot find it.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any good reason why you would need to run awk script from perl script? I mean, wouldn't be better to just do the same simple operation directly in Perl?

Comment: Symply cause my teacher wants to :(

Comment: `system("gawk", '/^>c/ {OUT=substr($0,2) ".fa";print " ">OUT}; OUT{print >OUT}', $string)`

Comment: This made the cript run but i'm not obtaining any output.It should give 1 or more fasta files.

Comment: It should give output.. It works for me on Ubuntu 14.04, Perl version 5.18.

Comment: Could you give a the full script?r

Comment: Maybe someone can help me to transalte it in perl, i'm just messing up everything :S

Comment: Hi Marc. I see that you asked another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27204971/translating-awk-script-into-perl). Did that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Splitting FASTA in perl is really easy.  Perl supports changing the record separator when reading a file.  If you change that to "\n>" then perl does all the work for you.

Here's an example:

```
use strict;

# Set the input record separator to the FASTA record separator
local $/ = "\n>";

while (<DATA>) {
    print "---- New sequence ---\n";
    # perl will put the separator at the end of the record,
    # so we need to remove the separator from the end,
    # and add it back at the beginning
    s/[\n>]+$//;
    s/^(?!>)/>/;
    print $_, "\n";
}

__DATA__
>seq1
ACGTACCTA
>seq2
TTCACTTAC
>seq3
ACCTTATTA
```