# translating awk script into perl

Tags: regex, perl, awk

I'm trying to translate this code into perl.

```
 gawk '/^>c/ {OUT=substr($0,2) ".fa";print " ">OUT}; OUT{print >OUT}' your_input
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Perl has a utility to do this for you called [a2p](http://perldoc.perl.org/a2p.html). If your script is call `script.awk` then you would run:

```
$ a2p script.awk
```

Which produces:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
    if $running_under_some_shell;
            # this emulates #! processing on NIH machines.
            # (remove #! line above if indigestible)

eval '$'.$1.'$2;' while $ARGV[0] =~ /^([A-Za-z_0-9]+=)(.*)/ && shift;
            # process any FOO=bar switches

$, = ' ';       # set output field separator
$\ = "\n";      # set output record separator

while (<>) {
    chomp;  # strip record separator
    if (/^>c/) {
    $OUT = substr($_, (2)-1) . '.fa';
    &Pick('>', $OUT) &&
        (print $fh ' ');
    }
    ;

    if ($OUT) {
    &Pick('>', $OUT) &&
        (print $fh $_);
    }
}

sub Pick {
    local($mode,$name,$pipe) = @_;
    $fh = $name;
    open($name,$mode.$name.$pipe) unless $openammeamme}++;
}
```

To save this to a file, use redirection:

```
$ a2p script.awk > script.pl
```

Perl also provides a tool for converting sed scripts: [s2p](http://perldoc.perl.org/s2p.html).

Comment: I just used it, and i ran the script.pl  but it gave me this message.   Bad name after fa'.

Comment: I believe `a2p` produces correct translation, but it's good only as long as you don't have to take a look on the source.

Comment: The script splits fasta files in other smaller files, the awk one works but the perl one doesn't :S

Comment: (Some year ago) I start learning perl by writing scrips in awk and a2p them to perl, and simplifying the result! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my ($outf,$OUT) ;
while(<>){
  if(/^>(c.*)/){ $OUT = "$1.fa";
                 close($outf) if $outf;
                 open($outf,">",$OUT);
                 print OUT " \n"}
  if($outf){ print $outf $_ }
}
```

if input is:

```
>caaa
sdf
sdff
>cbbb
ew
ew
```

Creats 2 files:

```
==> caaa.fa <==
>caaa
sdf
sdff
==> cbbb.fa <==
>cbbb
ew
ew
```

Answer (score 1):

This perl one liner should be equivalent of that awk command:

```
perl -ane 'if($F[0] =~ /^>c/){$OUT=substr($F[0],1).".fa"; if(OUT==null) {open(OUT,">$OUT");} print OUT " \n"} if ($OUT){print OUT $_} END{close(OUT)}' file
```

**Indented command line:**

```
perl -ane 'if ($F[0] =~ /^>c/) {
       $OUT = substr($F[0], 1).".fa"; 
       if (OUT==null) { open(OUT, ">$OUT") }
       print OUT " \n"
    }
    if ($OUT) {
       print OUT $_
    }
    END{close(OUT)
}' file
```

Comment: is it possible to use this as a function inside a perl script? sorry i'm really bad at this :(

Comment: I'm sure you can use this inside a perl script also. Sorry I am not a perl expert, just wanted to translate awk to perl using equivalent one liner logic.

Comment: Ah that's correct, thanks for pointing it out. Awk index starts at 1 instead of 0 of perl.

Comment: Sorry to insist: `length($F[0]-1)` for a typical  `length(">cfile"-1)` is `length(0-1)` = `length(-1)` = 2. The previous worked well for small file-ids (the ones we use in testing!:) ">ca"!. Your new naming solution is simpler and correct. "Indented command line" is a good idea!

Comment: @JJoao: Thanks for looking into this and your helpful comments.